# MySQL JOIN INSERT

Tags: mysql, join

I have tree table

```
a (a_col1, a_col12, a_col3)

b (b_col1, b_col12, b_col3)

c (c_col1, c_col12, c_col3)
```

I want to write the `b.b_col3` to `c.c_col3`
where  `a.a_col1` equals to `b.b_col12`.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
INSERT INTO c(c_col3)
SELECT a.a_col1, b.b_col12
FROM a LEFT JOIN b
ON 
a.a_col1 = b.b_col12;
```

Comment: Ask MySQL, last time i checked it reports if there are errors in queries

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to insert 2 columns value in single column, use something like below-

```
INSERT INTO c(c_col2,c_col3) SELECT a.a_col1, b.b_col12 FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.a_col1 = b.b_col12;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do both stuff with one query. You cannot `INSERT` and `SELECT` at the same time. Try first selecting and then inserting if it is possible.

Comment: You can insert data that you have selected from another table in the same query. Very commonly done.